# (aws-amplify) Why progressCallback only gets executed when the upload is finished?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-amplify

```
const stored = await Storage.put(filename, file, {
    contentType: file.type,
    customPrefix: customPrefix,
    progressCallback(progress) {
      console.log(progress)
    },
  })
```

This only executes once the upload gets finished. What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out and the reason is actually quite silly..... The file for uploading is too small (1mb) to get more than one update regarding progress.